# display the file descriptors of a process using python

Tags: python, proc, file-descriptors, vlc

How can I display the open file descriptors of a process in linux using python script? I tried using

```
readlink /proc/PID/fd/*
```

in python script but I am getting error.

```
/bin/sh: 2: /fd/*: not found
```

I think subprocess module will not give error. How will I use it to remove error if possible to display file descriptors?

Code:

```
import os
p=os.popen("pgrep -x vlc")
q=p.read()
print("Process ID of VLC : ",q)
process= os.popen("readlink /proc/"+str(q)+"/fd/*")
s=process.read()
print(s)
```

Comment: worth adding the remaining output from the script, e.g. that "Process ID of VLC : " output.

Comment: Process ID will keep changing everytime vlc is opened. So we can assume output as "Process ID of VLC : 12699"

Comment: Surely popen is for opening a single file.  Use of * is bogus ?

Comment: You are right but code is giving error.  When I run only the "readlink /proc/12699/fd/*" I am not getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to strip the trailing newline from `q`, ex. `q = q.strip()`.

Also, you'll have to think through what happens if there's more than one `vlc` running.

Comment: I'm curious to know , how did you find that? I spent lot of time in figuring out this error. But all effort was in vain.